# What is the least compressible probability distribution? (under entropy constraint, for an expected squared error metric)

Tags: pr.probability, probability-distributions, coding-theory

This is a [cross-post from cstheory](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/50804/what-is-the-least-compressible-probability-distribution-under-entropy-constrai) after a week with no answers/comments; I'm hoping someone here may have some thoughts.

Consider a distribution $\mathcal D$ over the reals, a real parameter $H\in\mathbb R^+$, and an integer parameter $k\in\mathbb N$.
The  [Entropy-Constrained Quantization](https://web.stanford.edu/class/ee398a/handouts/papers/Chou%20-%20EC%20VQ.pdf) problem asks what is the best set of quantization levels $Q\subset \mathbb R$, with $|Q|\le k$, that minimizes the expected squared distance to the closest level, under an entropy constraint $H$.

That is, if for all $q\in Q$ we denote the probability mass closest to it by $p_q$, then the entropy of the quantization levels set $H_Q=-\sum_{q\in Q}p_q\log_2 p_q$ must satisfy $H_Q\le H$, and the goal is to find
$$
\arg\min_{|Q|\le k\\H_Q\le H} \mathbb E_{X\sim \mathcal D}[\min\{(X-q)^2\mid q\in Q\}].
$$

The motivation comes from encoding long vectors whose entries are i.i.d. from $\mathcal D$ and compressing them before sending (or storing) them. The above paper gives an algorithm for approximating the optimal quantization level set.

For example, if $\mathcal D=\mathcal N(0,1)$ is the normal distribution and $k=2, H= 1$, the optimal solution is $Q=\{-\sqrt{2/\pi},\sqrt{2/\pi}\}$ (as the mean of the [half normal distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Half-normal_distribution) is $\sqrt{2/\pi}$).

The expected squared error, in this case, is the variance of the half-normal, i.e.,

$$
\min_{|Q|\le 2\\H_Q\le 1} \mathbb E_{X\sim \mathcal N(0,1)}[\min\{(X-q)^2\mid q\in Q\}]
=
\mathbb E_{X\sim \mathcal N(0,1)}\left[\min\left\{(X-q)^2\mid q\in \left\{-\sqrt{2/\pi},\sqrt{2/\pi}\right\}\right\}\right] = 1-2/\pi
.
$$

---

I am interested in distributions that are not "well compressible".

Specifically, suppose that we know that $\mathcal D$ has a variance of $1$.

> **What is $\arg\max_{\mathcal D\in\Delta(\mathbb R)}\min_{|Q|\le k\\H_Q\le H} \mathbb E_{X\sim\mathcal  D}[\min\{(X-q)^2\mid q\in Q\}]$ as a function of $k$ and $H$?**

If it makes things simpler, we can remove the cardinality constraint (and the parameter $k$).

Alternatively, assume that we have $k=2, H=1$. What would be the least compressible distribution with two quantization levels (and no non-trivial entropy constraint)?

Comment: Can the downvoter please explain?

Comment: It’s not me but crossposting is sometimes frowned upon

Comment: @kodlu - I did wait for a week and got no answer. Is there a more proper way to do that?

Comment: you can edit the question stating you got no answer for a week. otherwise, I think moderators may migrate questions, from one site to another.

Comment: @kodlu - sure, thanks. Migration may not be the best option here as some in TCS have found it interesting, and may miss if it's migrated and answered here.